# Html.Display and Html.Raw not displaying properly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view

I have the following code in my view. I cannot seem to show YES or NO unless I do it with :

```
    <td>
    <div class="hidden-lg hidden-sm hidden-md header_mobile">Chart Min/Max</div><div class="mobile_data">                                                                                  

        @if (item.Chart == true)
        {
             Html.Raw("YES");
        }
        else
        {
            Html.Raw("NO");
        }

     </div>
    </td>
```

but if I have the following it works:

```
   <div class="hidden-lg hidden-sm hidden-md header_mobile">Chart Min/Max</div><div class="mobile_data">                                                                                  

        @if (item.Chart == true)
        {
             <b>YES</b>
        }
        else
        {
             <b>NO</b>
        }

     </div>
```

I also tried with Html.Display instead of Html.Raw and I get the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The contents of a `{}` block are treated as code, not markup.

Therefore, your code calls those functions and ignores their return values (just like normal C#).

You need to tell Razor to print them: `@Html.Raw(...)`.